# why is ( A or B) and ((not A) or C) = ( A or B) and ((not A) or C) and ( B or C)?

Tags: boolean-logic

I can not proof that this both boolean formulas are logically equivalent. I think distributive and absorptive properties need to be used, but the `not a` and the existence of `c` clause are confusing me. Not sure how to handle both in the same expression.

Comment: What do you mean by "the existence clause of `c`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mainly have to use the distributive law:

I denote `!A` as not `A`, to make notation a bit shorter:

1.) restructuring the left side of the equation:

```
(A or B) and (!A or C)
```

Apply the distributive law:

```
(A and (!A or C)) or (B and (!A or C))
```

Simplify it a bit:

```
(A and !A) or (A and C) or (B and !A) or (B and C)
```

because (A and !A) is always false, this becomes:

```
(A and C) or (B and !A) or (B and C)
```

2.) restructuring the right side of the equation:

```
(A or B) and (!A or C) and (B or C)
(A and !A) or (A and C) or (B and !A) or (B and C)
```

because (A and !A) is always false, this becomes:

```
(A and C) or (B and !A) or (B and C)
```

Now you get the same expression on both sides of the equation and this tells you, that the two boolean expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was perfect. It took me a while to understand the right side of the equation simplification because it seemed to be a clause missing at the end "(B or C)" but as (B or C) and (B or C) = (B or C) I finally got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If we consider classical propositional logic, there are multiple ways to proof the semantic equivalence of two formulas:

The simplest method is to write down a [truth table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRMC-ttjhwM), i.e. you replace the propositional variables with truth values and calculate the result and show that both formulas have the same truth value given the assignment.

Moreover, you can easily see that (B or C) is a propositional resolvent; and resolvents are logical consequences of the assumptions. Therefore the addition of resolvents preserve semantic equivalence.